# Regex match if string contains "if" and "&"

Tags: regex

I need to implement a regex to check if a string contains a "if" and "&".
for example:

> if a & b // regex should to match here
>
> for a & b // regex not should to match here

I have tried, this regex (if|&), but in this case will be considerate if the string contains if OR ampersand...

Comment: Should it also match `a & if b`?

Comment: no, only if in the sequence, if * & * & * & ...

Comment: What could `a` and `b` be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note:** This answer assumes that `a` and `b` are words, that is, only containing the characters `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. If this is not what you want, replace `\w+` in the examples below appropriately.

```
if\s+(\w+)\s*&\s*(\w+)
```

matches the following:

```
if a & b
if foo&bar
```

Broken down:

- Match the word `if`
- Look for at least one whitespace character
- Match (and capture) a word
- Match 0 or more whitespace characters
- Match the `&` character
- Match 0 or more whitespace characters
- Match (and capture) a word